# How to apply modifiers in game runtime

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to figure out a logic node or logic brick way to apply a modifier on a mesh that is currently made but not applied.

Example: manipulating geonodes in game on a mesh, then applying it in game so the physics works correctly with the changed mesh.

Comment: What kind of "in game" do you mean? Blender does not have any officially supported game engine anymore.

Comment: Like durring a time line play back, "playing an animation", is there a way to just hit a button and have a modifyer applied durring that. Even with python is fine.